# Networks in VMs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, security

I've had a lot of issues with my virtual box i think its because i don't understand the concepts well enough of networking or VMs.

Problem:

1. So i was trying to connect my host machine and VM with netcat over the internet using port forwarding but i can't do it. My network on VM was Nat network. When i convert the NAT network to bridged adapter the internet doesn't work in the VM.
2. I wanted to switch the eth0 of my VM to monitor mode and i can't do that either.

Can anyone help with VMs and explain me in simpler terms what do i do for solving these issues.

The host machine is : Windows 10 64 bit

Virtual machine is : Kali linux

Comment: 1. What type of network is the VM (NAT or Bridged)?   2. Unlikely you can do that. You need to set up Mode on a wireless card and you cannot do that on the host machine. You need a USB Wireless card that supports Monitor mode and use USB passthrough int the guest machine to connect it.

Comment: Note, most consumer grade routers cannot allow devices inside the LAN to use port forwarding rules (basically internal hosts can't send traffic to the WAN side of the router). a router must support Nat Hairpinning/Reflective NAT in order to support using port forwarding traffic from the LAN back onto the LAN. Generally only enterprise routers support hairpinning.

Comment: Also, you need to add a great deal of clarity to your question (Edit the Question). What HOST operating system? What Guest Operating Systems?  What networking types?  Netcat is a networking utility for reading from and writing to network connections using TCP - it is not a connection protocol. How are you trying to connect machines to Host?

Comment: @FrankThomas I think there are alot of tutorials on port forwarding and by the looks of it the people displaying the tutorial never seemed like they work for an enterprise but i think you are correct so how do i connect two remote devices together? i am pursuing cyber security and trying to perform a reverse shell between my two pcs both on different network but trying to connect them using internet

Comment: @John How can i connect two pcs remotely? Like the one pc have full control over the other's shell.

Comment: Use Bridged Networking for the guest machines and then they appear just as real machines and you can connect like you normally would.

Comment: @John How do we normally connect to a machine sitting remotely ? It's shell specifically

Comment: You need to set up normal networking between machines.  I use NET USE for this. Ping just establishes that a connection exists.  See if you can RDP to the remote machine  to set it up.

Comment: Your question still lacks any reasonable clarity. You should set up a local example and test; not try remote first thing. This will help you learn. Then edit your question with specific examples.

Comment: @John i am able to connect things locally perfectly fine. The remote things bugs me i tried to configure my gateway with WAN but it doesn't works

Comment: You need a secure connection of some kind (I use VPN) to connect to the remote machine, use RDP and set it up.